# How do I extract words from a list in a text in R?

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to extract specific words from my observations, if those words are present.

```
a = c("friend", "cat", "dog")
b = "my friend has a dog"
```

if I use something like

```
results <- str_extract_all(b,a)
```

I would get a list of 3 which would state the frequency of each word in the a vector, including those which are not present in b.

I would like a vector, a list or a string containing just (and all) the words which are contained both in a and b.
Something like
results = ("friend", "dog")

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `paste` them to a single string with `str_c` and now it should work

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(b, str_c(a, collapse="|"))[[1]]
#[1] "friend" "dog"
```

---

Or convert to a `vector` by `unlist`

```
unlist(str_extract_all(b, a))
#[1] "friend" "dog"
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Since I need to scale it to more complex problems, what is the [[1]] for?

Comment: @emmecicubo in the first solution, it returns a `list` of one element.  So, either use `unlist` or just extract the first list element `[[`

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `regmatches`

```
> unlist(regmatches(b, gregexpr(paste0(a, collapse = "|"), b)))
[1] "friend" "dog"
```

or

```
> intersect(unlist(strsplit(b, "\\W+")), a)
[1] "friend" "dog"
```